# How to delete those tuples from table given, where salary of the instructor is less than average salary of corresponding department?

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable

Table schema is as shown:

```
INSTRUCTOR
__________
ID primary key,
salary,
dept_name
```

I want to delete such tuples which have salary less than average of their corresponding department. How to implement this query in SQL?

Comment: "How to delete those tuples from table given, where salary of the instructor is less than average salary of corresponding department?" Easy: calculate the average  per instructor for each department, then find individual instructors having less salary than the dept average.

Comment: I got the concept but not able to reflect it into SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this

First get the correspondent ID that have the salary below average by each dept

```
 Select ID from INSTRUCTOR a 
 Join 
 (Select dept_name, AVG(salary) avg_salary from INSTRUCTOR Group By dept_name) b 
 on a.dept_name = b.dept_name
 Where a.salary < b.avg_salary)
```

Then you can delete them by add another subquery

```
Delete From INSTRUCTOR Where ID In(
//Query Above//)
```

Comment: Wow I never thought of "join". Thanks!